# How i can implement inline 2heckout in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, 2checkout

I need to implement inline 2checkout in my store to reduce abandoment carts.

Answer (score 0):

You will notice you cannot setup this 2checkout with the **inline** option and Shopify.